# gnuplot: differences between script and interactive mode in macro processing

Tags: gnuplot

Iam using windows version of gnuplot

```
Version 4.6 patchlevel 3    last modified April 2013
```

i have a problem with running a gnuplot script via "load ..."

if i execute the following from the gnuplot commandline

```
set macro
test1 = "@test2"
test2 = "sin(x)"
pl @test1
```

it does work as expected. but if i put the code into a script and execute it from commandline

```
gnuplot> load 'test.gp'
```

i get the error

```
gnuplot> pl @test2
            ^
         "test.gp", line 4: invalid character @'
```

it seems that the macro processor does work differently (macro nesting depth) between script and interactive mode.
Is there any possibility to solve this?

#### edit:

i change the script as follows:

```
set macro
test1 = "sin(x)"
test2 = "@test1"
test3 = "@test2"
test4 = "@test3"
pl @test1
pl @test2
pl @test3
pl @test4
```

in interactive mode it aborts at `pl @test4` with `Too many levels of nested macros`.
On Scriptexecution it aborts on the second plot command after the first preprocessing step with:

```
gnuplot>     pl @test1
                ^
         "test.gp", line 7: invalid character @
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the `load` command is a bug, see [#1246 load command and macro expansion](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1246/), which was fixed in the development version as of 2013-06-28.

The limitation in the interactive mode is intended behavior, the `ChangeLog` says about the above bug fix:

> - src/misc.c (load_file): Expand macros up to 3 levels deep when 
>     stepping through a "load" operation.  This matches the depth allowed
>     for use at the top level command line.
>     Bug #1246

Comment: hmm - building with all terminals that i need or want is more complicated. i think i have to work around that issue.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch What OS do you have, if you are working on Debian/similar, I could give you a hand :)

Comment: fist line of question ;) - windows winXP32 to be exactly. building the cvs code works fine, but wxt and cairo support needs a lot of additional libs that i have to build first. unfortunately i have  no time for this.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch Sorry, but for compiling on Windows I'm completely lost. From time to time, there are new testing binaries for CVS, see http://www.gnuplot.info/development/binaries/. But I haven't tried them.